# g++ optimization breakes for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, optimization, g++

So, I have this codesnippet here

```cpp
for (int t = WILSON_TEMPORAL_START, t_i = 0; t <= WILSON_TEMPORAL_END; t++, t_i++)
{
    for (int r = WILSON_SPATIAL_START, r_i = 0; r <= WILSON_SPATIAL_END; r++, r_i++)
    {
        std::cout << r << " " << WILSON_SPATIAL_END << std::endl;
        wilson_loop[conf_id][t_i][r_i] = compute_wilson_loop(t, r, iu1, iu2);
    }
}
```

I run my g++ compiler in two different optimization versions `-O1` and `-O2`, but the terminal output is differently.

With `-O1`

```
2 12
3 12
4 12
5 12
6 12
7 12
8 12
9 12
10 12
11 12
12 12
2 12
3 12
4 12
...
```

With `-O2`

```
2 12
3 12
4 12
5 12
6 12
7 12
8 12
9 12
10 12
11 12
12 12
13 12
14 12
15 12
...
```

The code works fine if I change the inner loop to:

```cpp
for (int t = WILSON_TEMPORAL_START, t_i = 0; t <= WILSON_TEMPORAL_END; t++, t_i++)
{
    for (int r = WILSON_SPATIAL_START, r_i = 0; r <= WILSON_SPATIAL_END; r++, r_i++)
    {
        std::cout << r << " " << WILSON_SPATIAL_END << std::endl;
        // wilson_loop[conf_id][t_i][r_i] =
        compute_wilson_loop(t, r, iu1, iu2);
    }
}
```

Some useful definitions are:

```cpp
static double compute_wilson_loop(int time_extend, int space_extend, SUN_mat iu1[VOL][DIM], SUN_mat iu2[VOL][DIM])
void wilson::measure_wilson_loop(SUN_mat pu[VOL][DIM], double wilson_loop[CLEN][TLEN][SLEN], int conf_id) {
...
}
```

I know, that I can find a workaround here, but I really want to understand, why this happens.

Comment: How `compute_wilson_loop` is declared? What is `wilson_loop`?

Comment: If optimization affects the output from that loop, I'm guessing you have undefined behavior. You need to make a [mre] so we can see the declarations of all the variables involved. The `wilson_loop` array and the value of `conf_id` is especially interesting.

Comment: As an aside, that isn't how you spell _spatial_.

Comment: Compile your code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and `-O1` or `-O2`. Use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and perhaps the [Clang static analyser](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) and/or the  [address sanitizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)

Comment: `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak -fstack-check -lasan -lubsan` may also be useful

Comment: @Bomel Are you interested in getting this solved? You still haven't posted a [mre] or at least the definitions we need to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem, I made an error in defining the preprocessor constants. I'm still not sure, why it changes output when using a different optimization mode, but it works now :)